# Explain, please, a situation with the non-allocating operator new when buffer hasn't enough memory

Tags: c++, exception, memory, new-operator

I wrote this code:

```
 try
    {
        char* buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        int* bytes = new(buffer) int();
        *bytes = 10;
        std::cout<<*bytes;
        free(buffer);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
```

I think this code have a danger when I call operator **new**, because the **buffer** variable has less memory then the **bytes** variable requires. But the exception is not thrown. Do I have the ability to detect this bad situation or is this situation ok?

Comment: This is *undefined behavior*  - you cannot catch that since it doesn't throw any exception

Comment: C++ have never had any kind of basic bounds-checking. Not using valid pointers or too small buffers is the responsibilities of the programmers.

Comment: I think that if you want to use placement new correclty you first have to wrap it in a containing class and do some checking yourself. Eg. throw  std::bad_alloc, if buffer is to small or return a nullptr. The placement new operator itself won't throw. Read more here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: *But the exception is not thrown.* - What makes you think it *should* be thrown?

Comment: In addition, [`std::align`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) would also be required.

Comment: *Do I have the ability to detect this bad situation...?*  Yes, you have the ability to detect this bad situation, but in this code you did not detect the bad situation.  *...or is this situation ok?*  No, this situation is not okay.

Comment: You wrote this code *why*? And *what* exception are you expecting to be thrown? and why?

Answer (score 0):

> But the exception is not thrown.

You seem to expect an exception, but there is none. Your code has undefined behavior.

> Do I have the ability to detect this bad situation or is this situation ok?

You can throw an exception:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
 try
    {
        char* buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        if constexpr (sizeof(char) != sizeof(int)) throw std::runtime_error("buffer cannot hold an int");
        int* bytes = new(buffer) int();
        *bytes = 10;
        std::cout<<*bytes;
        free(buffer);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Even `if constexpr`. :)

Comment: Technically `if constexpr` is invalid here because the condition doesn't depend on the immediate context, although many compilers will accept this anyways.

Comment: @user2407038 oh right I was too fast in applying the comment. The code isnt sound anyhow, if this check is made it should be placed in a template where constexpr can be applied, I just didnt want to change too much on OPs code

Comment: @user2407038: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if), it can be used outside of template... Trick is that code should still be correct inside (so code as `if (sizeof(char) != sizeof(int))) { char zero_size_array_in_false_case[sizeof(int) - sizeof(char)]; }` is invalid in false case).

Comment: @Jarod42 cool, thanks for clarifiying. I was too fixated on discarding the branches, because thats the usual motivation to use it. And I just remembered that this is possible only in templated context. refixed the fix